# Can a Facebook page create an event in a Facebook group the page admins?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, privacy, facebook-groups, facebook-events

Can a Facebook page create an event in a Facebook group the page admins? A regular user, that is also admin, can do it.

The page can also create events and publish it its (the page's) log, but such events are public. I have a private group with a page as the admin and want to create an event for the group that is only visible to the members of the group. This should be a very common use case, shouldn't it!?

---

According to this [video](https://www.facebook.com/business/learn/video/create-event-facebook) it should be possible but when I follow that process the UI doesn't look like in the clip and I don't have these options.